# android program hangs before onCreate is called (beginner)

Tags: android, debugging, android-debug, adb

I needed some sample code to test out the `AudioRecord` class and I came across this website
[LINK TO THE SOURCE CODE](http://androidsourcecode.blogspot.kr/2013/07/android-audio-demo-audiotrack.html)
However the program doesn't run, and hangs after a while. When the program starts it gives  blank screen and does not do anything, and after a while a message box pops up saying the program is not responding and whether I want to close it.
So I added `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HERE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` as the first line of `onCreate()` in `MainActivity`, but even this toast does not show up on the screen. Where are possible locations where a program may hang, before even calling onCreate()? How can I locate that line of code? I tested it on the emulator.

Comment: plz post your codes here

Comment: The code is too long, So I've posted a link to the code

Comment: its hard to help without your logcat,if your oncreate doesnt get called maybe it's a problem in your manifest file.read your Logcat again when crash happens

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if its the exact cause but in the XML layout file it makes references to `@+id/textView1` but there is no `TextView` defined in the XML file.
This may refer to the `TextView` that the SDK creates by default to show the "Hello World" label but has been removed from the example given.
In fact looking at the code in the layout more, the line `android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"` is wrong because it has `@+id/` which means it is trying to assign a new `id/` to `android:layout_alignLeft` instead of making it match the value `"@id/textView1"`.